# Is there any work on distributional vector fields?

Tags: differential-equations, schwartz-distributions

I know that people think about weak solutions to PDEs by turning a differential equation into an integral equation. Have people studied any analogue to this where we *start* with an integral equation, defined by a distribution rather than a vector field?

For instance, let $v$ be a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\delta_0 + 1$. I can write down an integral equation

$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \omega'(t)\;\mathrm{d}t = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v(t) \omega(t)\;\mathrm{d}t$$

where $\omega$ ranges over all compactly-supported smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

I believe that the function

$$x(t) = \begin{cases} t + C & \text{if $t < 0$} \\ t + C + 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

is then a solution to this integral equation.

If this works in simple cases, I'd like to generalize, as discussed [here](https://www.localcharts.org/t/differential-equations-with-jumps/16830), but it was recommended that I see if anyone had thought about the simple case first.

Edit: This was the wrong question to ask for what I'm interested in. @Willy-wong correctly answered this question, but what I'm actually interested in is here: [Existence and Uniqueness of Solutions to a Distributional Ordinary Differential Equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467417/existence-and-uniqueness-of-solutions-to-a-distributional-ordinary-differential)

Comment: you probably want $-x(t)$ to be the solution (to cancel the minus sign from partial integration)

Comment: The fact that every distribution on the line has a primitive which is unique up to a constant is a basic and elementary fact which can be found early on in pretty well any introduction, in particular in the initial treatment of Laurent Schwartz.  The proof is simple and elementary.

Comment: Yes @CarloBeenakker you are right, I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 3):

The specific question you ask here is basically about the existence of distributional antiderivatives. The answer is "yes", and that you can also recover the "$+C$".

The main problem is this: **not all test functions $\phi$ arise as a derivative of another test function**. A necessary and sufficient condition is that $\int \phi = 0$. This means that the requirement
$$ \langle x,\psi'\rangle = \langle v,\psi\rangle \tag{*}\label{eq:basic}$$
for a given distribution $v$, at best, only defines what $x$ should be on a codimension-1 subspace of the space of test functions. Hence *necessarily* there will be some freedom.

#### Uniqueness

Suppose $x$ and $\hat{x}$ both solve \eqref{eq:basic}, then we have that $x - \hat{x}$ is such that, for any $\phi$ with $\int\phi = 0$ (and hence there is some $\psi$ such that $\phi = \psi'$)
$$ \langle x - \hat{x},\phi\rangle = \langle v,\psi\rangle - \langle v,\psi\rangle = 0 $$
Now as the set $\{\int \phi = 0\}$ is **defined** by the vanishing of a linear functional (the mapping $\phi \mapsto \int \phi$ is a distribution), this means that $x - \hat{x}$ must be a scalar multiple of the functional $\phi \mapsto \int \phi$.

In calculus notation this means that $x = \hat{x} + C$.

#### Existence

Fix $\eta$ a test function with $\int \eta = 1$. Given a test function $\phi$, the function $\phi - (\int\phi)\cdot \eta$ has total integral $0$, and hence we can find a test function $\psi$ such that $\psi' = \phi - (\int\phi)\cdot \eta$.

I claim that the formula
$$ \langle x, \phi \rangle = \langle v, \psi\rangle $$
defines a distribution. Linearity is obvious. It suffices to prove continuity.

Suppose $\phi$ has support in $[a,b]$, and $\eta$ has support in $[\alpha,\beta]$. Then we know $\psi$ is supported in $[\min(a,\alpha),\max(b,\beta)]$, and we have, from basic calculus, that for $s\in [\min(a,\alpha),\max(b,\beta)]$

$$ |\psi(s)| \leq (|b-a| \sup_{[a,b]} |\phi|) \cdot (1 + | \beta - \alpha| \sup |\eta|) $$

the higher derivative bounds are easier

$$ |\psi^{(k)}(s)| \leq \sup_{[a,b]} |\phi^{(k-1)}| + |b-a| (\sup_{[a,b]} |\phi|) \sup_{[\alpha,\beta]} |\eta^{(k-1)}| $$

Now let $[a,b]$ be fixed. For any $\phi$ with support in this interval, we have $\psi$ has support in $[\min(a,\alpha),\max(b,\beta)]$, and hence there exists a constant $C$ and a number $n$ (assumed to be $\geq 1$ for convenience) such that
$$ |\langle v,\psi \rangle| \leq C \sup \{ |\psi^{(k)}(s)| : s \in [\min(a,\alpha),\max(b,\beta)], k \leq n \} $$
and using the bounds above, we see that
$$ |\langle x,\phi \rangle| \leq C' \sup \{ |\phi^{(k)}(s)| : s \in [a,b], k \leq n-1 \} $$
with
$$ C' = C \cdot \big[ 1 + |b-a| \big( 1 + |\beta - \alpha| \sup |\eta| + \sup_{s\in [\beta-\alpha], k \leq n-1} |\eta^{(k)}(s)| \big) \big] $$
Note that since $\eta$ is fixed, the values $\alpha, \beta$ and the $C^k$ norms of $\eta$ are considered fixed constants.

#### Explicit example

In your case, fix $\eta$ a test functions with unit mass that is supported on the interval $[1,2]$, then we know that $\eta$ is the derivative of some smooth function $H$ that is identically $0$ on $(-\infty,1]$ and identically $1$ on $[2,\infty)$.

Similarly, given an arbitrary test function $\phi$ with compact support $[a,b]$, we know that it can be written as the derivative of some function $\Phi$ that is identically $0$ on $(-\infty,a]$ and $\int\phi$ on $[b,\infty)$.

So $\psi = \Phi - (\int\phi) H$ is a test function. Observe that
$$ \langle \delta_0 + 1,\psi\rangle = \Phi(0) + \int_a^{\max(b,2)} \Phi - \int \phi \cdot \int_1^{\max(b,2)} H $$
On the other hand, integrating by parts we find
$$ \int_{\leq 0} t \phi(t) + \int_{\geq 0} (1 + t)\phi(t) = 
\int_a^b t \Phi' + \int_0^b \Phi' = (b+1) \int \phi - \int_a^b \Phi - \Phi(0) $$
So if we set $\hat{x}$ to be the function that equals $-t$ when $t \leq 0$ and $-t -1$ when $t > 0$, we find
$$ \langle \delta_0 + 1,\psi\rangle - \langle \hat{x},\phi\rangle = 
\int_b^{\max(b,2)} \Phi + \int\phi \cdot \Big(b+1 - \int_1^2 H - \int_2^{\max(b,2)} H \Big) $$
We simplify to
$$ = \int\phi \cdot \Big( |\max(b,2)-b| + b+1 - \int_1^2 H - |\max(b,2)-2| \Big) = \int\phi \cdot \Big( 3 - \int_1^2 H \Big) $$
showing that the distributions
$$ \phi \mapsto \langle \delta_0 + 1, \psi\rangle \text{ and } \phi \mapsto \langle \hat{x},\phi\rangle $$
different by a constant ($3 - \int_1^2 H$) times the distribution $\phi \mapsto \int \phi$, exactly as expected from the discussions above.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from signs, aren't you just asking for a function/distribution whose distributional derivative is $\delta$ (or $\delta+1$, or whatever)? Those integrals are by-abuse-of-notation just expressions for the pairing between distributions and very-nice functions.