# Existence and uniqueness of solutions to a distributional ordinary differential equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, schwartz-distributions

Suppose that $v$ is a distribution on the real line. Then under what conditions can I solve the differential equation

$$
\dot{x}(t) = v(x(t))
$$

which I might interpret as an integral equation

$$
-\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)\; \omega'(t)\; \mathrm{d}t = \int_{-\infty}^\infty v(x(t)) \; \omega(t)\;\mathrm{d}t
$$

where $\omega$ ranges over compactly-supported test functions.

For instance, if $v(x) = \delta_1(x) + x$, then I would expect the following to be a solution

$$ x(t) = \begin{cases} e^t & \text{if $t < 1$} \\ (1 + e)e^{t-1} & \text{if $t > 1$} \end{cases} $$

Edit:

Sorry, I've been confusing my $x$s and $t$s. It should be

$$ x(t) = \begin{cases} e^t & \text{if $t < 0$} \\ 2e^t & \text{if $t > 0$} \end{cases} $$

Comment: What you wrote cannot be a solution. You seem to be under the impression that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_1(x(t)) \omega(t) ~dt = \omega(1)$ for the particular choice of function $x$ that you wrote. But that is not the case. This integration should only factor in those values of $t$ for which $x(t) = 1$. Luckily for you, your function $x(t) = 1$ when $t = 0$, and $x$ is smooth near there (with derivative $1$). So in fact you have, for your given $x$, that $$ \int \delta_1(x(t)) \omega(t) ~dt = \omega(0)$$. And hence what you wrote is not a solution.

Comment: By the way, the integral expression you write doesn't make sense in general. Given a distribution $v$, the composition $v(x(t))$ is only guaranteed to make sense if $x$ is sufficiently smooth at all $t$ such that $x(t)$ is in the singular support of $v$. I doubt that is the correct way to interpret what you want.

Comment: With your update, you run into a different problem: $\delta_1(x)$ is **not** well-defined as a distribution. In standard theory $\delta_1(x(t))$ is a well-defined distribution for $x$ with the property "if $x(t) =1$, then $x'(t)$ exists and is not equal to zero." This doesn't hold in your case. Please provide a definition of what $v(x)$ means in this case (and in general).

Comment: Really what I'm looking for is a suitable definition, or really what I was looking for is if experts in the theory of distributions had studied this kind of problem before.

People do scientific simulations all the time with jumps in them, where a "discrete event" happens when you hit a certain threshold, see: https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/features/callback_functions/, or elastic collisions in physics software. So I was trying to figure out if this could be "geometrized" using distribution theory, but I guess not.

Comment: My second answer can be interpreted as the following, then: you have a continuous call back function $v$ that does something when its argument hits the value 1. You have a process that approaches the value 1 as time increases toward 0, but jumps to 2 right after time 0. Does your call back fire? To implement the process numerically, you have it increase toward 1. And at time $t = 0$, it _starts at $1$_ and _jumps to $2$_ all the while $t$ hasn't changed. Whether your callback fires is now dependent on, when evaluating it at $t = 0$, whether the callback is used before or after the jump.

Comment: I guess the programming term for this is: you've set up a **race condition** and the output is ill defined.

Comment: That said, I think if you insist all of your functions are one-sided differentiable and [cadlag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g), there is probably a suitable theory that you can develop. (In fact, it probably has been, by folks studying stochastic processes.)

Comment: Ah, the word cadlag brings up memories of an analysis class long past... this is exactly the next clue I was looking for!

Comment: With regard to the race condition, the way that this typically works is that you run a root finding algorithm on the differential equation without the callback to figure out when exactly you will hit the callback, and then you run the callback at the time that the root finding algorithm returns. So in practice there isn't a race condition... I don't know if this addresses what you were concerned about though.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that in numerical simulations you don't actually get a race condition. My point is more that in principle there MAY be a race condition, and hence your simulation code will have to define the algorithm in such a way that the outcome is repeatable. What you outlined is exactly one such solution. However, note that from the "pure mathematics" those two things (root finding and checking the call back) should "happen at the same time"; the numerics are designed to resolve the ambiguity that appears in the "pure math" (at least its naive interpretation).

Comment: That makes sense to me. And it also makes sense that moving to cadlag gives the math a similar ability to "bias the race condition" in the same way that a numerical method would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This second answer specifically addresses the issue of trying to interpret $v\circ x$ when $x$ is not regular and $v$ is a distribution. I will tie this into the [edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/467417/3) to illustrate the problem.

The question is, give that $x$ is the function that is $e^t$ when $t < 0$ and $2e^t$ when $t > 0$, what is the distribution $\delta_1\circ x$. Specifically, is it the case that
$$ \int \delta_1(x(t)) \omega(t) = \omega(0) $$
for all test functions $\omega$?

I claim that this cannot be a well-defined operation. One way to see this is through approximations to the identity. Ideally we would like it to be the case that whatever the definition is, if we take a sequence of smooth functions $f_\epsilon$ that converges (as a distribution) to $\delta_1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, that
$$ \int f_\epsilon(x(t)) \omega(t) \to \omega(0) $$

***Case 1: symmetric bumps***

Let $f$ be a smooth, even, bump function ([here's a concrete example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Concrete_example)). Let

$$ f_\epsilon(x) = \frac1\epsilon f(\frac{x-1}{\epsilon}) $$

Standard arguments (see the above linked Wikipedia page) shows that for any test function $g$, you have

$$ \int f_\epsilon(x) g(x) dx \to g(1) $$

Now look at $f_\epsilon(x(t))$. We see that for $t < 0$ but approaching $0$, that $x(t) \approx 1 + t$ by Taylor expansion, and so $f_\epsilon(x(t)) \approx f_\epsilon(1 + t)$ for $t < 0$.

On the other hand, for $t > 0$ you have $x(t) \approx 2 + 2t$, and hence for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$ we have $f_\epsilon(x(t)) = 0$ when $t = 0$.

**In particular, only "half" of the bump remains.**

If you carry out this computation and take the limit, indeed you will find that

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int f_\epsilon(x(t)) \omega(t) dt = \frac12 \omega(0) $$

and you are off by a factor of 2.

***Case 2: asymmetric bumps***

Now take the same $f$ as before, but define

$$ g^\pm_\epsilon(x) = \frac1\epsilon f( \frac{x-1 \pm \epsilon}{\epsilon}) $$

Note that $g^+_\epsilon$ is supported on $[1-2\epsilon,1]$ and $g^-_\epsilon$ is supported on $[1,1+2\epsilon]$.

As long as $\omega$ is a continuous function, we see that

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int g^{\pm}(x) \omega(x) dx = \omega(1) $$

So again both of these families converge to $\delta_1$. But now, if you run the same analysis as we did before, you will find that

- $ g^+_\epsilon\circ x(t)$ converges to the distribution $\delta_0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, while
- $ g^-_\epsilon\circ x(t)$ is always the zero distribution, for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.

(in fact, you can also come up with versions $h_\epsilon$ such that $h_\epsilon \circ x(t)$ converges to the distribution $\lambda \delta_0$, for any $\lambda\in (0,1)$.)

---

In general, if you have a piecewise smooth function $x(t)$, you can always play this sort of games with distributions $v$ with singular support at a non-smooth point of $x$.

Fundamentally, this is not too surprising: the theory of distribution is based on a linear phenomenon (pairing of functions and integrating, thereby defining a linear functional on the space of functions). Nonlinear changes of domain are not guarantee to play well with linearity. In the case where the change of variables is differentiable and regular, we know that the change is "almost linear" and so we have some hope of recovering something sensible using calculus. But as soon as you give up on this almost linearity you start running into trouble.

Answer (score 6):

Let me explain several reasons why I think what you are trying to do cannot work.

#### Algebra

Suppose, for a moment, that $v(x(t))$ makes sense as a pull-back distribution. Then we would be allowed to perform the change of variables
$$ \int v(x(t)) \omega(t) ~dt = \int v(x) \omega(t(x)) \frac{dt}{dx} ~ dx $$
here $t(x)$ is the inverse function to $x(t)$, and the integral on the right has domain suitably selected. The left hand side can be treated similarly
$$ \int x(t) \omega'(t) ~dt = \int x \frac{d\omega}{dt}(t(x)) \frac{dt}{dx} dx = \int x \frac{d\omega\circ t}{dx} ~dx = - \int \omega(t(x)) ~dx $$
So by comparison you will need that
$$ \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{v(x)} $$
**which is nothing more than exactly what you get from doing separation of variables on $\frac{dx}{dt} = v(x)$ formally**.

This has the benefit that it casts the problem in the same setting as [your previous question about antiderivatives of distributions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/467336/3948). And shows that what is fundamentally the issue in interpreting your "distribution valued ODE" is in essentially defining what the "multiplicative inverse" of a distribution is.

In the case where $v$ is given by a possibly discontinuous function that is bounded away from zero, the notion of $\frac{1}{v}$ is clear. Indeed, you also recover the standard theory when $v$ is suitably nice.

Even when the standard theory cannot apply you get something interesting. For example, suppose $v$ is the Heaviside function that is $1$ on $[0,\infty)$ and $-1$ on $(-\infty,0)$. The formal manipulation will give $v = 1/v$, so that the the function $t(x)$ solves the distributional equation
$$ \frac{dt}{dx} = v(x) $$
which tells us that $t = |x| + C$. Indeed, if you invert (locally) this expression you will get solutions to the original ODE.

**But then a problem clearly presents itself: given a distribution, how to you make sense of its multiplicative inverse?** Is there a distribution $\psi$ such that $\psi \delta_0 = 1$ (here $1$ is the distribution corresponding to $\omega \mapsto \int \omega$)?

#### Analysis

In the previous discussion I mentioned the requirement that $v$ is bounded away from zero, so that $1/v$ can be defined. In fact, this shows another potential issue with your interpretation. When $v$ has zeros, even in the classical case where $v$ is Lipschitz, you have solutions $x$ for which the maximal domain is not the whole real line. Consider for example $x' = x^2$. A typical solution would look like $x(t) = \frac{1}{c-t}$ with domain $t\in (c,\infty)$ or $t\in (-\infty,c)$. How would you extend the solution past the singularity at $c$?

Additionally, even supposing you make the "inspired" choice that the correct solution is $x(t) = \frac{1}{c-t}$ for all $t \neq c$, this function is not locally integrable near $c$, and you run into the question how you interpret it as a distribution.

To be clear: **we've started with a smooth $v$ for which $x$ is not necessarily well-defined as a distribution**.

Okay, you may argue that the $1/t$ singularity is not too bad, since we know how to take Cauchy principal values. Fine, how about the right hand side? You are trying to look at a distribution which would look like
$$ \omega \mapsto \int \frac{\omega(t)}{(c-t)^2} ~dt $$
Now principal values cannot save you!

*This I think is a significant problem, as ideally you would like whatever theory you develop to be a generalization of what works when $v$ is a nice ordinary function. Instead, you've given an "interpretation" that doesn't even make sense in this case.*

This is not even touching on the well-known examples with $v$ a continuous function having non-unique solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, to this and the other question! This is teaching me a lot about distributions.

I do have a question about this answer though: at the beginning, you assume that there is a suitable inverse $t(x)$. In the case that $x(t)$ has a discontinuity at $t = t_1$, jumping from $x_-$ to $x_+$, then would $t(x) = t_1$ for $x \in [x_-,x_+]$? Then this would imply that $1/v(x)$ should be $0$ for $x \in [x_-, x_+]$, which kind of makes sense to me as we are "dividing by infinity".

Comment: @cheshircat: you cannot just divide like that. Let me put a separate answer to address it.